how can I add a panel to another form's Flowlayoutpanel in C#
Newbie here, I want to create the panel in another form that contains some controls Such as A Label and a PictureBox, and send it to the main Form to add it and display it in the Main Form's Flowlayoutpanel when I press a Button just like adding new food to the menu list, so my problem is that when I create the panel It doesn't show up in the Main form's flowlayoutpanel.
here is the codes I wrote:
PanelCreation Form
the code for selecting image

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string path;

      OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          path = ofd.FileName;

          pictureBox1.ImageLocation = path;
          pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
      }

  }

the code for creating the panel

  public Panel panel1;

  public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      
      panel1 = new Panel();
      panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      panel1.Size = new Size(275, 300);
      panel1.BackColor = Color.White;

      Panel panel2 = new Panel();
      panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      panel2.Size = new Size(10, 30);
      panel2.Location = new Point(3, 14);
      panel2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 20, 20);
      panel1.Controls.Add(panel2);

      Label title = new Label();
      title.Text = textBox1.Text;
      title.Font = new Font("Georgia", 18, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
      title.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      title.Location = new Point(13, 14);
      title.AutoSize = true;
      panel1.Controls.Add(title);


Main Form

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Form2 form2 = new Form2();


            Panel panel = form2.panel1;


            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);

        }


As a general rule, insure the "parent container" is big enough; or is able to "autosize" with it's children (unless you resize with code); which usually requires a "measure and layout" pass after playing with the "visual tree" in any case. (Just saying)
